# yeoman build:minify renames images -> angularjs ng-src fails

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am using yeoman + angular and tried out 'yeoman build:minify'. This fails because the task rev:img renames all images. Afterwards, the dynamic sources (see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) do not work anymore.

Does someone know a trick to fix this? E.g. would it be possible to avoid the image renaming?

Comment: I think this is related to yeoman's issue at here: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/822, and it's not solved yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is currently a [known issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/822) and we'll try to fix it soon.

In the meantime you can try out one of the suggested workarounds in [this thread](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/406#issuecomment-9826527).

Just replace the `rev` config with this:

```
rev: {
   img: ['images/**','!images/ignore/**']
}
```

and place all your dynamic images in `images/ignore/`

Comment: thanks! Btw: Same needs to be done for images used in (s)css files.

Answer (score 8):

In recent versions of [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and its [Gruntfile.js](http://yeoman.io/authoring/gruntfile.html) you can add folder of image to its `filerev` task. So that your `filerev` task looks like this:

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      /* Here you'll see some ignoring: */
      '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/some_image.png',
      '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/ignore',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
  }
},
```