# How to set image from AngularJS controller in grunt-filerev?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am using [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) in my Grunt tasks. It generates random filenames to disable browser caching. So far so good but how can I set an image from an AngularJS controller? Following is not working because my foo.png gets renamed to foo12345.png

Template:

```
<img ng-src={{my_image}}></img>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
$scope.my_image = 'images/foo.png';
```

I already did the same question on [GitHub (#54)](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev/issues/54#issuecomment-56531513)

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?

Comment: Seems like it was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212153/yeoman-buildminify-renames-images-angularjs-ng-src-fails